# Unexpected T_STRING error (PHP)

Tags: php

I can normally catch these easy, but......

```
function linear_regression($x, $y) {

// calculate number points
$n = count($x);

// ensure both arrays of points are the same size
if ($n != count($y)) {

trigger_error("linear_regression(): Number of elements in coordinate arrays do not match.", E_USER_ERROR);

}

// calculate sums
$x_sum = array_sum($x);
$y_sum = array_sum($y);

$xx_sum = 0;
$xy_sum = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

$xy_sum+=($x[$i]*$y[$i]);
$xx_sum+=($x[$i]*$x[$i]);

  }



  // calculate slope
  //$m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));

  $divisor = (($n * $xx_sum) – ($x_sum * $x_sum));
if ($divisor == 0){
 $m = 0;
} else {
$m = (($n * $xy_sum) – ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / $divisor;
}


  // calculate intercept
  $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $n;

  // return result
  return array("m"=>$m, "b"=>$b);

}

var_dump( linear_regression(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 4), array(1.5, 1.6, 2.1, 3.0, 6)) );
```

The error is happening here `$divisor = (($n * $xx_sum) – ($x_sum * $x_sum));`

Any ideas why?

Comment: You don't need brackets in this expression (and others): `(($n * $xx_sum) – ($x_sum * $x_sum));`. PHP's operator precedence follows arithmetic conventions.

Comment: The error persists even if you take off the outer set of parenthesis.

Comment: okay so I copied this over and ran it and got the error.  _I was shocked._  And then I slowly started to add/remove variables and I don't know why that happened but it works now?  Same whitespace and brackets and everything.  I just replaced the variables with `1` and added/removed things.  I have no idea why it happened or what I fixed.

Comment: Is the minus sign actually a minus sign. I've had situations where I was copy/pasting and the minus symbol was an html entity an not the actual symbol.

Comment: @Jeff: You're a genius!  The minus sign wasn't a true minus sign.  (Stupid copy/paste fail!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: @gtilflm - how did you get that fake minus sign in your code?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: Copy/pasting from webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign is a fancy unicode dash (I think the em dash) instead of the regular ascii - character.

Comment: The way I found it btw was just copy/pasting the code from firefox into an rxvt to run it on the php command line. rxvt pasted it as \uxxxx instead of -, triggering a warning and error from php and immediately looking different too.

Comment: @JakeGould: Actually it was "Jeff" in the comments.  Beat Adam by a nose.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me how I discovered that, but your "-" is not a real "-", is another character, but have the same apparence

Ok you didn't asked me, but I have discovered at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ , it doesn't recognize yours "-" character

Now working code with real "-", you can copy an paste, and see:

```
function linear_regression($x, $y) {

// calculate number points
$n = count($x);

// ensure both arrays of points are the same size
if ($n != count($y)) {

trigger_error("linear_regression(): Number of elements in coordinate arrays do not match.", E_USER_ERROR);

}

// calculate sums
$x_sum = array_sum($x);
$y_sum = array_sum($y);

$xx_sum = 0;
$xy_sum = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

$xy_sum+=($x[$i]*$y[$i]);
$xx_sum+=($x[$i]*$x[$i]);

  }



  // calculate slope
  //$m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));

  $divisor = (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));
if ($divisor == 0){
 $m = 0;
} else {
$m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / $divisor;
}


  // calculate intercept
  $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $n;

  // return result
  return array("m"=>$m, "b"=>$b);

}

var_dump( linear_regression(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 4), array(1.5, 1.6, 2.1, 3.0, 6)) );
```

Comment: how did that happen??  i was _shocked_ when i copied and pasted the code and the error was real... lol... how do you think he got a `-` that was fake?

Comment: I don't have php at my pc so I used http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it recognized that "-" was actually another character per encoding. Was pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I retyped the offending line like this:

```
$divisor = (($n*$xx_sum)-($x_sum * $x_sum));
```

The error disappeared. After a bit of poking the error seems to be related to the minus sign in the middle. deleting it and retyping it seems to fix the problem.

See [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uwc-g9u):

Answer (score 0):

Adam is right, but also, you didn’t close the `for` loop. Here try this.

Also, the minus sign was the wrong sign here:

```
$divisor = (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));
```

As well as here:

```
$m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / $divisor;
```

My cleaned up version of your function with the closed `for` loop in place as well here.

```
function linear_regression($x, $y) {

  // calculate number points
  $n = count($x);

  // ensure both arrays of points are the same size
  if ($n != count($y)) {
    trigger_error("linear_regression(): Number of elements in coordinate arrays do not match.", E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  // calculate sums
  $x_sum = array_sum($x);
  $y_sum = array_sum($y);

  $xx_sum = 0;
  $xy_sum = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $xy_sum+=($x[$i]*$y[$i]);
    $xx_sum+=($x[$i]*$x[$i]);

    // calculate slope
    //$m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));

    $divisor = (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));
    if ($divisor == 0) {
      $m = 0;
    }
    else {
      $m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / $divisor;
    }

    // calculate intercept
    $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $n;

  } 

  // return result
  return array("m"=>$m, "b"=>$b);

} // linear_regression
```